# bun in summarization 'report pane' Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have my live model from a tabular SSAS; in the model pane I can clearly see that it will summarize it by SUM:

[image]

The exact same columns in the Report pane do not have this, and its very strange, it must have the same properties:

[image]

This bug impacts because, I do not have the measures created, I just use those done automatically by power bi, and in this case they do not work.

Comment: Are your columns set to the correct datatypes? Perhaps your fields imported as Text rather than Decimal/Money/Whole Number

Comment: nope, it says 'whole number'. In any case; I guess, it should have the same symbol in both report pane and model pane.

Comment: I think to answer this question we'd need some more information. Are there any transformations being done in the data load? Can you show a screenshot of the columns data type set as a whole number? The Sigma should appear if those columns are, in fact, set as a numeric datatype

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[Tabular Editor](https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/tabular-editor/)** External Tool to inspect the fields that work vs. the ones that don't.

[image: Tabular Editor]

As a work-around, you can always create measures in Power BI, even with a live connection.